# Process Assets non rails project

Tags: rake, project, ember.js, asset-pipeline

I'm building a project with PHP for server side and Ember.js for the client side.

i've wrote all scripts in CoffeScript, templates in .hbs files and .scss files for the styles, for now i'm using rake-pipeline for compiling all, but i have a couple of problems:

- How to organize the dependencies
- How to include scripts in other files
- How to determine the order of the scripts

for now i have a hardcode AssetFile for sort the scripts in the final .js file but my app become more complex and some files need grows and split into more files but i have the problems before mention.

**AssetFile**

```
output BUILD_DIR
input SRC_DIR do
  match '**/*.handlebars' do
    handlebars :precompile => true
    concat '0.js'
  end

  match '**/lib/*.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '1.js'
  end
  match '**/app.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '2.js'
  end
  match '**/controller/*.coffee' do
    coffee_script
    concat '3.js'
  end
end
```

my project layout is like

```
Resources/
   assets/
      js/         # Are like my vendors (jquery, ember, etc...)
      images/     # i copy this without process
      styles/     # Here are .scss and .sass files
   scripts/
      templates/  # It's a directory tree with files .hbs 
      controller/ # Dirs with arbitrary names
      lib/
      ...
      main.coffee # main point, ej: App = Rkmax.App.create();App.initialize();
```

you can see the main trouble is give a correct order when concat .js files generate by coffee compiler, I've seen some projects in rails and using the sentence `require`inside .coffe files but do not know how to make rake-pipeline understand this sentence.

Comment: Head to https://github.com/emberjs/todos/ and look at `Assetfile` and `index.html` to know how to compile js files in to one and how to load js in your html

Comment: This solution is similar to mine, have hardcoded some routes and order. Although I have built my own solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while. I decided to use instead of rakepipeline, [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) has a similar system to compile everything you need

### Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'sprockets-sass'
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffe-script'
```

### Rakefile

```
require 'sprockets'
require 'logger'
require 'fileutils'
require 'pathname'

task :compile => :clean do
    sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new(ROOT)

    sprockets.append_path SOURCE_DIR.to_s

    %w( app.js vendor.s template.js ).each do |bundle|
        assets = sprockets.find_asset(bundle)
        ext = bundle.split(".")[1]
        name = assets.pathname.basename(assets.pathname.extname)
        FileUtils.mkpath BUILD_DIR.join(ext)
        assets.write_to BUILD_DIR.join(ext, "#{name}.#{ext}")    
    end
end
```

Sprockets has "Directive Processor" like

- require
- include
- require_self

they let me organize dependencies easy. the only thing was that it did not process `.handlebars` default but i wrote a simple `handlebars_template.rb`

### handlebars_template.rb

```
require 'tilt'
require 'json'

module Sprockets
  class HandlebarsTemplate < Tilt::Template
    self.default_mime_type = 'application/javascript'    

    def prepare
    end

    # Compile template data
    def evaluate(scope, locals, &block)
      "Ember.TEMPLATES['#{scope.logical_path.split("/")[1..-1].join("/")}']=Ember.Handlebars.compile(#{data.to_json});\n"
    end
  end
end
```

register in the right place and voila! process my templates

```
register_engine 'handlebars', ::Sprockets::HandlebarsTemplate
register_engine 'hbs',        ::Sprockets::HandlebarsTemplate
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of `require` is going to be your solution. Declaring dependencies using `require` lets your tooling concatenate and/or load modules is the right order.

Most rake-pipeline projects that use `require` are using minispade ([github](https://github.com/wycats/minispade)) and it's rake-pipeline filter companion, MinispadeFilter. ([github](https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters/blob/master/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/minispade_filter.rb)).

You might also want to look at Iridium ([github](https://github.com/radiumsoftware/iridium)) as an example of a tool that wraps these tools up with others.

Comment: I was looking minispade but documentation is practically nil

Comment: @rkmax I agree, it would be good to have docs for minispade. In fairness, it is only 70 lines of JS, so it's not hard to read and understand. When I was learning it, I found this blog post helpful: http://blog.nulayer.com/post/23294069876/building-simple-javascript-libraries-with-rake-pipeline